# How to process user register and data-flow between identityserver(.net identity) and js client

Tags: identityserver4

I have three projects and two EF Contexts

1. IdentityServer4 with .Net Identity(Identity Context)
2. .Net API (Bussiness Context)
3. Js Client(Angular)

I have some ideas about implementing register;

1. When user clicks register button in Js Client redirect to IdentityServers /Account/Register url. After user successfully registered, send necessary data to API and generate related rows. Then I need to get a new token to the Js Client which I dont know how to do it after register.
2. When user clicks Register Button in Js Client, user goes to Register page in Js Client, send credentials to API and API sends credentials to IdentityServer. API gets Jwt token from IdentityServer and if user successfully created, generate necessary rows in database then returns jwt to Js Client.

Main problem is how can I get the Jwt token after user registers to the IdentityServer and how can I set token to localStorage or cookies safely in Js Client. I heard some hacks like send jwt as url parameter but it does not sounds good for security reasons.
How did you implemented register?

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 looks better than the other. All the login/registration logic should be handled at the Auth Server. There when user hits save it will create a row in your database. Couldn't understand what you mean by

> send necessary data to API and generate related rows

Your auth server should be talking to your database and should be responsible for saving newly registered users or logins.

- When user successfully registers, you give them the login screen.
- When they successfully login - they will be redirected to your client app
- On the client app (since its js client) you can use oidc-client library to manage user status (logged in/not logged in) and JWT
  tokens. Check it out [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki) !

So in a nutshell, user needs to login successfully to get valid tokens - registration alone doesn't help!

Comment: I mean I have an UserInfo class in Bussiness context which has relationships with other entities with fluent API.
So I'll implement as you suggest. The other thing is, I want users to redirect to client after register. I mean when they register they also login.

Comment: you can certainly do that. You can configure register method in account controller but make sure you to sign in the user using signIn manager. Check login method for all the checks!